# How to block modal until api request is resolved

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

**The question**

What is the best way I can block the `hideModal()` action, ESC keydown handler, overlay click handler until the `EditDepartmentsModal::submitChanges()`'s underlying http request is resolved?

**Update**

What I think I can do is to:

- intercept api calls, set PENDING status at another vuex module
- check if PENDING is true in the `hideModal()` action.

Wouldn't that couple the vuex modules? Is it a good idea at all?

---

**The details**

I'm using a separate vuex module for a modal visibility control (as proposed [in the article](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/building-a-modal-dialog-with-vue-and-vuex/)):

```
...
state: { modalVisible: false, },
mutations: {
  SET_MODAL_VISIBLE(state) { state.modalVisible = true; },
  SET_MODAL_INVISIBLE(state) { state.modalVisible = false; },
},
actions: {
  showModal(context) { context.commit('SET_MODAL_VISIBLE'); },
  hideModal(context) { context.commit('SET_MODAL_INVISIBLE'); },
}
...
```

The **Modal.vue** (excerpt):

```
<template>
  <div class="ui-modal">
    <div v-if="visible" @click="closeOnOverlayClicked && hideModal()">
      <div :class="cssContainerClasses" @click.stop>
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
...
mounted() {
  if(this.closeOnEscPressed) this.handleEscPressed();
},
computed: {
  ...mapState('modal', { visible: state => state.modalVisible, }),
},
methods: {
  // handles ESC keydown, overlay click
  ...mapActions('modal', ['hideModal',]), 
  // other methods ...
}
...
```

The parent **EditDepartmentsModal.vue** component embeds the **Modal.vue** and allows firing its `submitChanges()`, `cancel()` methods:

```
<template>
  <modal>
    <form>
      <!-- ... -->
      <div class="modal-actions">
        <button @click="submitChanges()">Submit</button>
        <button @click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </modal>      
</template>

<script>
  ...  
  methods: {
    submitChanges() {
      // DepartmentsHttpService was imported before
      let rq = DepartmentsHttpService.saveChanges();
      rq.then(r => { this.hideModal(); });
      rq.catch(e => { /* show errors, log */ this.hideModal(); });
    },
    cancel() {
      // vuex mapped action
      this.hideModal();
    }
  }
  ...

</script>
```

For api calls I decided to utilize ([article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48494196/vue-do-api-calls-belong-in-vuex)) service objects wrapping the **axios** requests:

```
// DepartmentsHttpService.js
import {HTTP} from '../http';    
export default { saveChanges(params) { return HTTP.post('departments', params); }, };
```

---

**Question quality disclaimer**

If you need more of my components code I'll update the question. Maybe it's not perfectly formulated right now, I'm open to make edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question properly, it seems easy to solve with Promises

```
async submitChanges() {
  try {
    // Store the Promise so that we can wait for it from any point in our component
    this.saveChangesPromise = DepartmentsHttpService.saveChanges();
    await this.saveChangesPromise;
    this.hideModal();
  } catch(e) {
    /* show errors, log */ this.hideModal();
  }
},

async handleEscapePressed() {
  // If somebody has decided to save, wait for the save action to be finished before we close
  if (this.saveChangesPromise){
    await this.saveChangesPromise;
  }
  this.hideModal();
}
```